# PowerShell won't run Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I'm trying to make a secret santa Python script. I have a VM running Ubuntu, in which I ran the script, no problems there. Next step, I wanted to run it in PowerShell. I have Python installed, version 2.7.10 (checked vis PowerShell). I have run other scripts before (and even different versions of this script) in PowerShell before, so I know I have that set up correctly. But for some reason, this one won't run. I even put a `print` statement as the first real line after the `import`s, but it isn't reached. Am I using a built in function that doesn't work with Windows?

```
import random
import pprint

people = ["Billy", "Joe", "Bob", "Sam", "John", "Kyle"]
chosen = {}
preventions = [["Joe", "Bob"], ["Sam", "John"]]

print "Test"
for person in people:
    groupExists = False
    for preventionGroup in preventions:
        if person in preventionGroup:
            groupExists = True

    if not groupExists:
        preventions.append([person])

for preventionGroup in preventions:
    for person in preventionGroup:
        while True:
            # print "Hi"
            num = random.randrange(0,6)
            # print num
            giftee = people[num]

            if giftee not in preventionGroup and giftee not in list(chosen.values()):
                chosen[person] = giftee
                break

# pprint.pprint(chosen)
for key, value in chosen.iteritems():
    print "Gifter: " + key
    raw_input()
    print "Giftee: " + value
    raw_input()
```

It's named `Secret Santa.py`, so the PowerShell line to run the script is

```
python '.\Secret Santa.py'
```

And yes, I have checked to make sure I'm in the same directory as the file.

Comment: what's the name of your script, and can you [edit] your question to include the way to run the command wrong powershell?

Comment: I think I found the problem, it doesn't like the `raw_input()` function. I even tried `input()` even though I'm in python 2.7.10 (just to check), and that didn't work either. So, what's the way to wait for input in windows?

Comment: since you're running windows, you could use `os.system("pause")`.

Comment: `import os` doesn't seem to work. I get the same pausing bug.

Comment: Define "won't run". Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say? Does the script hang? At which point? Did you try running `python -i` from PowerShell and then manually enter the statements from your script? I just tested the code you posted with Python 2.7.11 (Windows 7, PowerShell 4) and can't reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: It just hangs, I put a `print` just after the `import`s, and it doesn't get called, meaning at the very least, it isn't caught in an infinite loop later on. Then, if I do python -i while trying to use `import os`, I get "NameError: name 'os' is not defined", if I try and use `raw_input()`, it just hangs after the `print "Gifter: " + key`. Pressing enter does nothing.

Comment: Looked into it a bit more, apparently it's because I was using the ISE, and a normal powershell console can use `raw_input()` just fine